# using google maps api as image gallery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-maps

does anyone know an efficient way to use the google maps api to replace the map and fill with custom images?

Somewhat like this page: http://www.postdigitalcultures.ch/

is angularjs the way? (something of which I am not sure of how to use!)

thanks

Comment: MapType and OverlayMapType, but you'll need some kind of tile server to answer with a  deterministic tile for the  combination of x, y and zoom

Comment: thanks, i will look at it. i should say that it is this effect precisely: http://www.postdigitalcultures.ch/current